# How to save websocket responses to mongodb

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am connected to a websocket using node.js ws module.
Each time i get response with event called "add_items" i want to save it to mLab cloud database.

Websocket response looks like this

```
{"event":"add_items","data":[

{"id":["13635936204"],
"m":"name1",
"p": 14.00}

{"id":["13635936220"],
"m":"name2",
"p": 50.00}

]}
```

What would be the best way to connect to database and save new data ?

Currently i use .forEach method to loop through array , than create objects for each new item and save it to databse using db.collection.insert() method. But the problem is that i might get over 50 items per sec and sometimes i get error "mongodb connection timed out". Is it possible to use mongoose module to simplify this process ?

Comment: https://www.npmjs.com/package/mongoose-write-stream

Comment: yes you can use mongoose module and use insertMany method of mongoose so you can directly pass the array received as an argument and it will save all object at once.

Answer (score 0):

You can use MongoDB's `insertMany`:

```
db.collection.insertMany(websocketEvent.data);
```

Where `websocketEvent` is the response received via Websocket. Check `insertMany` syntax and info [here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.insertMany/).

**UPDATE:**

Maybe you can loop through the array calling `updateOne` and decide to update or insert using the `arrayFilters` field, something like this:

```
websocketEvent.data.forEach(event => {
    db.collection.updateOne(
       { _id: ObjectID(event.id[0])},
       { $set: { m: event.m, p: event.p }},
       {
         upsert: true,
         arrayFilters: [ <filterdocument1>, ... ]
       }
    )
}
```

Check the [docs for info on the `arrayFilters` field for `updateOne`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.updateOne/).

Comment: the problem with .insertMany is that i want to loop through all items to check if they already exists in database and if they do what was the time i saved it etc ...